# Scala private access modifier scope

Tags: scala

I have code with companion object and defined constructor as private:

```
class Person private[Person] (var age: Int, var name: String) {
  private[Person] def this(name: String) = this(0, name)
}

private class Employee(age: Int, name: String) extends Person(age, name)

private class Worker(age: Int, name: String) extends Person(age, name)

object Person {
  def prettyPrint(p: Person) = println("name:%s age:%s".format(p.name, p.age))
  def apply(age: Int, name: String) = new Person(age, name)
  def apply() = new Person(0, "undefined")
  def apply(age: Int, name: String, personType: String): Person = {
    if (personType == "worker") new Worker(age, name)
    else if (personType == "employee") new Employee(age, name)
    else new Person(age, name)
   }

}
```

My question is why another object in same package also have access to this private constructor. I added private[this] so others didn't have access to it but nor companion had. Can I have private properties for class and companion object only ?

Comment: Isn't it because the constructor is called by the class, so it correct. Maybe you should make a private function which returns the resulting class.

Comment: @Lukasz in your examples the `private` modifier applies to the constructors and not to the properties. Do you really want to restrict calls to the constructor or just have private fields ?

Comment: `private class Employee(age: Int, name: String) extends Person(age, name)` slays the compiler on 2.9.1. Congrats!

Comment: Yes indeed :) I tried that exactly on 2.9.1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

This code does not compile. Both `Employee` and `Worker` try to access the private constructor, and are rightfully denied access.

Your question speaks of a private variable, but there's no variable declared private.

So either your example is incomplete, or it is incorrect. Please correct the example so we can answer the question.

Comment: Ok so issue is with compiler bug that stops it from finishing so I looked ok in Eclipse while it didn't compile at all.